# Low beam is a lot brighter than high beam, why?

Tags: motorcycle, headlight, bulbs

I recently changed the headlight of my 2004 Cagiva Raptor 125 and now i noticed that the low beam is a lot brighter than the high beam. The low beam seems normal but the high beam looks like it has some sort of resistance blocking the current's normal flow.
I noticed that when the low beam is on, the high beam indicator is on (but not fully lit...). I checked the wires and they are not crossing or anything. It uses a regular H4 bulb that works perfectly fine. I tested both high and low beam on the low beam wire. Before doing the wiring i checked the voltage for each light switch position so i wouldn't mess it up... what could be the problem? There is no blown fuse... the entire bike has a total of 2 fuses, non of which are blown (since the high beam is partilly lit). The low beam voltage is the same as the on of the battery (12,6v) whereas the high beam voltage is 11.2-11.3 volts.

Comment: Check the resistance on the switch itself. I wonder if the high beam circuit has some sort of resistance causing the drop in voltage.